# Google Analytics: Multiple domain, One tracking ID, one email report

Tags: google-analytics, multiple-domains, reporting

I created a new Tracking ID for 10 Drupal sites. However, why all 10 sites reports are the same in my Google Analytics?

---

***update: added additional information***

Here are 10 sites info I got

#### Drupal site 1: siteA.com


Code on Google Analytics Module: **UA-00000001-1**


#### Drupal site 1: siteB.com


Code on Google Analytics Module: **UA-00000001-2**


#### Drupal site 1: siteC.com


Code on Google Analytics Module: **UA-00000001-3**
. . . and so on

**PS: For each site, I added the**

### same 2nd tracking ID and code

on Custom Javascript code in Google Analytics Module
code snippet(before):

```
_gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "none"]);
_gaq.push(["_setAllowLinker", true]);
```

Code snippet (after):

```
_gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-00000002-1”]);
_gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "none"]);
_gaq.push(["_setAllowLinker", true]);
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
```

#### Also I added a Filter for each Google Analytics View on tracking ID UA-00000002-1.

**on SiteA.com**
Filter Type: - Predfined Filter> Include only > Traffic to the hostname > that begin with
Hostname: SiteA.com

**on SiteB.com**
Filter Type: - Predfined Filter> Include only > Traffic to the hostname > that begin with
Hostname: SiteB.com

**on SiteC.com**
Filter Type: - Predfined Filter> Include only > Traffic to the hostname > that begin with
Hostname: SiteC.com

... and so on

Comment: You'll need to add your tracking code here and how it's implemented.

Comment: @dan what do you mean? What type of tracking code do I need to add? I already added the Tracking ID on Google Analytics module on each Drupal site(total 10 sites). Is there some kind of setting I have to do on Google Analytics account?

Comment: To help others answer this, you should copy the Google Analytics tracking code appearing in the source code of your site(s) and add it to your question (see [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#quickstart) as to what the code looks like). You can track [multiple domains](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite) under the same profile, but you'll need to create separate profiles if you want to see them separately.

Comment: @dan I updated my post with additional info. Hope this help others to answer my question.

Comment: @dan when you say the separate profiles, do you mean "View"?

Comment: @dan actually the Google Analytics seem to work. I may need to wait another day for a full day report.

Comment: Initially the question only stated `I created a new Tracking ID for 10 Drupal sites`, which read as _one_ tracking ID for all 10 sites. After your edits however, it looks like you're using different ones for each site (which is why it's best to always include details). Glad it seems to be working - I'm going to close this so that others don't unnecessarily spend time on it.

Comment: @dan Ty dan. Please close this issue

Comment: @dan I'm using one Tracking ID as 2nd ID for all 10 sites. Please see the "same 2nd tracking ID and code" section.

Comment: The code is working but I still don't know how to make it as one email report